# Non-recursive version of modifyList?

Tags: r, recursion

The behaviour of `modifyList` is to modify lists recursively - i.e., in this case, the `fixed` is a nested list which will also be "modified":

```
default.options <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = "hello", fixed = list(a = 1))
user.options <- list(b = 3, e = 0, fixed = list())

opts <- modifyList(default.options, user.options)
dput(opts)
# list(a = 1, b = 3, c = "hello", fixed = list(a = 1), e = 0)
```

But, what if I don't want it to follow the sublist `fixed` recursively, but just replace it as a whole, i.e. the desired result is this? :

```
list(a = 1, b = 3, c = "hello", fixed = list(), e = 0)
```

Is there a simple way to do this non-recursive list modification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
default.options[names(user.options)] <- user.options

identical(default.options, list(a = 1, b = 3, c = "hello", fixed = list(), e = 0))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wow, really? So simple? I am little bit confused with the usage of single `[` for indexing the list. I was used to always use `[[` for lists. Why `[` and not `[[`?

Comment: I really like this, and way simpler than my first thought! @TMS `[` returns a list when subsetting a single element; compare `foo <- list(a = list(0)); foo["a"]; foo[["a"]]` or even `foo <- list(a = 0); foo["a"]; foo[["a"]]`; and it should be used when dealing with more than one element; compare `foo <- list(a = 0, b = 1); foo[c("a", "b")]; foo[[c("a", "b")]]`

Comment: @TMS You can see this in the help file (`help("[[")`): "The most important distinction between [, [[ and $ is that the [ can select more than one element whereas the other two select a single element."

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me the simple answer is just to copy and modify the source code of `modfiyList()` to remove the recursive part of it:

```
modify_list_nonrecursive <- function (x, val, keep.null = FALSE) {
    stopifnot(is.list(x), is.list(val))
    xnames <- names(x)
    vnames <- names(val)
    vnames <- vnames[nzchar(vnames)]
    if (keep.null) {
        for (v in vnames) {
            x[v] <-  val[v]
        }
    }
    else {
        for (v in vnames) {
            x[[v]] <- val[[v]]
        }
    }
    return(x)
}

default.options <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = "hello", fixed = list(a = 1))
user.options <- list(b = 3, e = 0, fixed = list())

opts <- modifyList(default.options, user.options)
dput(opts)
# list(a = 1, b = 3, c = "hello", fixed = list(a = 1), e = 0)

opts <- modify_list_nonrecursive(default.options, user.options)
dput(opts)
# list(a = 1, b = 3, c = "hello", fixed = list(), e = 0)
```

The original source code of `modifyList()` was

```
modifyList

function (x, val, keep.null = FALSE) 
{
    stopifnot(is.list(x), is.list(val))
    xnames <- names(x)
    vnames <- names(val)
    vnames <- vnames[nzchar(vnames)]
    if (keep.null) {
        for (v in vnames) {
            x[v] <- if (v %in% xnames && is.list(x[[v]]) && is.list(val[[v]])) 
                list(modifyList(x[[v]], val[[v]], keep.null = keep.null))
            else val[v]
        }
    }
    else {
        for (v in vnames) {
            x[[v]] <- if (v %in% xnames && is.list(x[[v]]) && 
                is.list(val[[v]])) 
                modifyList(x[[v]], val[[v]], keep.null = keep.null)
            else val[[v]]
        }
    }
    x
}
```

So you can see you just have to delete some conditionals with recursive calls and it works just fine!